# NestJS Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I'm trying to figure out NestJS and there's an error in the arrays. Please tell me how to fix it? I was trying to figure it out and realized that the error is in " advantages:TopPageAdvantage[];". For some reason, he does not want to add an array. Without an array everything works correctly.

version in package.json:

```
"@typegoose/typegoose": "^8.2.0",
"mongoose": "^6.0.3",
```

version in Docker: `image: mongo:4.4.4`.

```
[Nest] 16224  - 31.08.2021, 22:31:41   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at mapOptions (E:\Обучение node.js\udemy_nest_js\top-api\node_modules\@typegoose\typegoose\src\internal\utils.ts:460:50)
    at Object.mapArrayOptions (E:\Обучение node.js\udemy_nest_js\top-api\node_modules\@typegoose\typegoose\src\internal\utils.ts:389:18)
    at Object.processProp (E:\Обучение node.js\udemy_nest_js\top-api\node_modules\@typegoose\typegoose\src\internal\processProp.ts:469:18)
    at Object._buildSchema (E:\Обучение node.js\udemy_nest_js\top-api\node_modules\@typegoose\typegoose\src\internal\schema.ts:59:7)
    at buildSchema (E:\Обучение node.js\udemy_nest_js\top-api\node_modules\@typegoose\typegoose\src\typegoose.ts:140:9)
    at Object.getModelForClass (E:\Обучение node.js\udemy_nest_js\top-api\node_modules\@typegoose\typegoose\src\typegoose.ts:77:58)
    at InstanceWrapper.modelFactory [as metatype] (E:\Обучение node.js\udemy_nest_js\top-api\node_modules\nestjs-typegoose\dist\typegoose.providers.js:22:58)
    at Injector.instantiateClass (E:\Обучение node.js\udemy_nest_js\top-api\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:294:55)
    at callback (E:\Обучение node.js\udemy_nest_js\top-api\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:43:41)
    at Injector.resolveConstructorParams (E:\Обучение node.js\udemy_nest_js\top-api\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:119:24)
```

Page module:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypegooseModule } from "nestjs-typegoose";
import { TopPageController } from './top-page.controller';
import { TopPageModel } from './top-page.model';

@Module({
  controllers: [TopPageController],
   imports:[
     TypegooseModule.forFeature([
        {
          typegooseClass: TopPageModel,
          schemaOptions: {
            collection:'TopPage'
          }
        }
     ])
   ]
})
export class TopPageModule {}
```

Page model:

```
import { Base, TimeStamps } from '@typegoose/typegoose/lib/defaultClasses';
import { prop } from '@typegoose/typegoose';
import { ProductCharacteristic } from '../product/product.model';

export enum TopLevelCategory{
  Courses,
  Services,
  Books,
  Products
}

export class HhData{
  @prop()
  count:number;

  @prop()
  juniorSalary:number;

  @prop()
  middleSalary:number;

  @prop()
  seniorSalary:number;
}

export class TopPageAdvantage{
  @prop()
  title:string;

  @prop()
  description:string;
}

export interface TopPageModel extends Base{}
export class TopPageModel extends TimeStamps{

  @prop({ enum: TopLevelCategory })
  firstCategory:TopLevelCategory;

  @prop()
  secondCategory:string;

  @prop({unique:true})
  alias:string;

  @prop()
  title:string;

  @prop()
  category:string;

  @prop({type: () => HhData})
  hh?:HhData;

  @prop({type: () => [TopPageAdvantage]})
  advantages:TopPageAdvantage[];

  @prop()
  seoText:string;

  @prop()
  tagsTitle:string;

  @prop({type: () => [String]})
  tags:string[];
}
```

Comment: Does typegoose support mongo v4? TypeORM has the same problem when trying to use Mongo v4, which is why I ask

Comment: I'm trying to do the courses and everything works there without any problems. Consequently typegoose support mongo v4

Answer (score 0):

Currently facing the same issue with typegoose .
it happens when try to create a subdocument using this

```
  @prop({type: () => [TopPageAdvantage]})
  advantages:TopPageAdvantage[];
```

or

```
  @Field(type => [Rate])
  @Property({ type: () => Rate, default: [] })
  ratings: Rate[];
```

from
https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/blob/v1.0.0/examples/typegoose/entities/recipe.ts

So i had to remove the type for it to work . which result in a mixed
object

Answer (score 0):

in mongoose you can directly store array items as below

```
users: [{ type: String }],
```

if you want to store class type then you can specify object type in array

```
users: [{ type: Object }],
```